# Cannot import jsonstreamer / cannot pip install yajl-py

Tags: python, json, yajl

I'm trying to use JSON streamer to parse a large 11gb JSON file. JSONstreamer appears to be the only package that streams the file without having to load the entire file into memory first.

When I try to import jsonstreamer in python I get this error.

```
OSError: Yajl cannot be found.
```

When I try to pip install yajl I get this error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

However all there files are there

I downloaded the yajl.dll file from their webpage and added it into my C:\Windows\SysWOW64 dir.

Don't really have any ideas how to proceed because it seems like I am stuck.

Comment: hello, have you found solution to this problem? I am having exactly same problem as you do.

Comment: I believe the issue is that there is problems with this package. I recommend using a package that can work with the file as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it's fixed installing git on the machine: there is a dependency for it in pip3 scripts.

The key was on the log, you can see how a git subprocess is executed:

```
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-01hs0gev/yajl/setup.py) egg_info for package yajl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-01hs0gev/yajl/setup.py", line 64, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['git', 'submodule', 'update',])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git'
```